# Error: failed to create deliver client for orderer: failed to load config for OrdererClient: unable to load orderer.tls.rootcert.file: open/varskeyfil

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, minifab

I'm trying to bring up the minifabric network based on my own `spec.yaml` file. When I bring up the minifabric network using the command `minifab up` it show me this error:

Any solution?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctDUE.png)

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been solved.

Just need to remove the organization name from the orderer nodes so that it can be as follows:

```
orderer1.example.com
```

and you can replace the `example` with the name used in your spec file.